# Edittext switch to english in android application

Tags: android, android-edittext, ime

I have a layout in android application with a bunch of edittext inputs.

Some inputs require user to enter data in russian language.
last field is a email field. Email can be english (99%), but also can include international letters. So it will be very convinient to switch keyboard to english on this input field on focus (with ability to switch to another language).

I tried to force english and then remove this limitation using .post:

```
emailEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                emailEdit.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_FORCE_ASCII);
            }
            emailEdit.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    emailEdit.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But this code just force keyboard to english only without ability to switch to another language.

Is there any way to switch inputtext soft keyboard to english without "english only" limitation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, especially not across all keyboard apps.  Most keyboards maintain their own input language-  this is not a concept of the Android OS.  So it can't effect it.  And that flag can be interpreted in weird ways by different keyboard.  Most will ignore it.  Some will set the language to english.  Others will perform odd translations like changing accented characters to their base character.  Apps really have very limited control over the keyboard on Android.